Issues Installing pysqlcipher3 on Windows 2024
I'm trying to install pysqlcipher3 on Windows, but it seems that the process is mainly designed for Linux. When I attempt to install it using pip, I encounter the following error:

PS
D:\josea\José_Andrés\Programación\Pyhton\Codigos\VerificadorEstacionamiento>
pip install pysqlcipher3 Collecting pysqlcipher3   Using cached
pysqlcipher3-1.2.0.tar.gz (102 kB)   Preparing metadata (setup.py) ...
done Building wheels for collected packages: pysqlcipher3   Building
wheel for pysqlcipher3 (setup.py) ... done   WARNING: Legacy build of
wheel for 'pysqlcipher3' created no files.   Command arguments:
'D:\josea\José_Andrés\Programación\Pyhton\Codigos\VerificadorEstacionamiento\venv\Scripts\python.exe'
-u -c '   exec(compile('"'"''"'"''"'"'
# This is  -- a caller that pip uses to run
setup.py
#
# - It imports setuptools before invoking setup.py, to enable
projects that directly
#   import from distutils.core to work with newer packaging
standards.
# - It provides a clear error message when setuptools is not
installed.
# - It sets sys.argv[0] to the underlying setup.py, when
invoking setup.py so
#   setuptools doesn'"'"'t think the script is -c. This avoids
the following warning:
#     manifest_maker: standard file '"'"'-c'"'"' not found".
# - It generates a shim setup.py, for handling setup.cfg-only
projects.   import os, sys, tokenize
try:
import setuptools   except ImportError as error:
print(
"ERROR: Can not execute setup.py since setuptools is not available in "
"the build environment.",
file=sys.stderr,
)
sys.exit(1)
file = %r   sys.argv[0] = file
if os.path.exists(file):
filename = file
with tokenize.open(file) as f:
setup_py_code = f.read()   else:
filename = ""
setup_py_code = "from setuptools import setup; setup()"
exec(compile(setup_py_code, filename, "exec"))   '"'"''"'"''"'"' %
('"'"'C:\Users\josea\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1bfv914d\pysqlcipher3_b196db9a45cb4114bcee0627db05c021\setup.py'"'"',),
"", "exec"))' bdist_wheel -d
'C:\Users\josea\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-gxaob0da'   Command
output: [use --verbose to show]   Running setup.py clean for
pysqlcipher3 Failed to build pysqlcipher3 ERROR: ERROR: Failed to
build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects
(pysqlcipher3)

I have been watching some outdated tutorials that use nmake and other tools, but these videos are from several years ago. They mention that we need to specify the OpenSSL path in the Makefile.msc as C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\VC\static, but now in 2024, this folder no longer exists. Instead, the path is C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\VC\x64\ with four folders (MD, MDd, MT, MTd).
I’m stuck at this point, and I need help to successfully install pysqlcipher3 on Windows.
Any advice or updated instructions would be greatly appreciated!

What is your python version?

Python 3.11.9,.

Just with this command on WIndows works:
pip install pysqlite3-wheels

On Linux:
pip install pysqlcipher3


Your question was how to install pysqlcipher3 on Windows 2024 but you're providing an answer that doesn't match the question. pysqlite3-wheels is a different package from pysqlcipher3.

According to the GitHub repo for installing pysqlcipher3-for-windows:
Before installing pysqlcipher3:

libsqlcipher must already be installed on your system, with the process dependent on your operating system.

You have to install the TLC package and OpenSSL package.

Ensure you are using Python >= 3.7 and <3.10 (which obviously you're not using as seen in your comment).


See this GitHub repo for a detailed guide on installing pysqlcipher3 for windows.
